# Items apparently being published to web twice every time

Tags: publishing, lucene

I have an odd situation where I publish from master to web a single item with the following options:

- Republish
- No Child Items
- No Related Items
- Only 1 language
- Only 1 version

And the item is published twice. I can see from the logs that the updated items are two, and I can see from the custom index ComputeFieldValue method that the code is executed twice.

I am, of course, concerned about performance when large amount of items are published. I went through the logs and index configuration files without luck.

What is causing this? How can I start troubleshooting this issue?

EDIT:
this is my development machine, which is both CM and CD. The stacktrace is exactly the same in both instances when the ComputeFieldValue is hit.

Comment: Start here: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/search_index_troubleshooting/

Comment: Can you share a bit more on your environment?  Is it a 1-box setup, or do you have CM and CD servers - and if so, does this behaviour happen on both?

Comment: Thanks for the link, will read. I have updated the question with some context information.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause/solution?

Comment: Not yet, sorry.

Comment: What publishing targets (are there multiple) are under:  /sitecore/system/Publishing targets   ?

Comment: Is that URL or a folder path?